# Printf() stopped working over serial

Tags: c, memory, embedded

I'm going to go out on a limb here, as I am not sure what code you would need to see if any.

I am working on some embedded code that has a user interface over serial. When I moved to new ethernet drivers only half of the printf() statements that are used to send text over the connection work, so I have a lot of blank command output. Any idea as to what would have caused this?

I read online that this *might* have to do with stack size?

I will gladly post more information to clarify in any areas needed.

Thanks!

Example 1:

```
// List commands and their summary
// It is assumed that a command with an empty summary does not 
// actually exist (helpful for conditional compilation)
printf( "Shell commands:\n" );   **This line Prints**
while( 1 )
{
  if( ph->cmd == NULL )
    break;
  if( strlen( ph->help_summary ) > 0 )
    printf( "  %-6s - %s\n", ph->cmd, ph->help_summary ); **This does not**
  ph ++;
}
printf( "For more information use 'help <command>'.\n" ); **This line prints**
}
```

When I step through the code the printf() is reached and does in-fact run, but no output goes over the serial connection.

**Answer, for the lazy to scroll:**

My driver had some debug code filled with printf()'s that wasn't commented out on release.... I have since removed it and the problem has gone away. Somehow that must have caused some problems in memory.

Comment: Why do you suspect that the Ethernet driver affects your serial communication?

Comment: With the other driver this problem doesn't occur. I am just wondering what in the phy or ethernet driver would cause this. Mainly if this type of problem occurs often and there is a certain type of problem I should be looking for.

Comment: Lets say you have 5 printf() statements. Are the blank ones all at one end? I.e. do 1,2 print okay and 3,4,5 are missing? Or vice versa.

Comment: Normal printf()'s seem to work, however there are some that use strucures to define things like help menu options with the different command names and descriptions the ones that work off of these structures are the ones that fail. I'll paste some of that code above.

Comment: I have this feeling that as it goes through the loop it ends up filling up the stack so it just runs out of space. But wouldn't that make it only print about half of the structure's worth of entries and not the last printf()? Instead it prints the first and last, but not the middle, weird.

Comment: How does the output actually looks like? can you provide some output along with your question?

Comment: Are you confident that 1. `ph->help_summary != NULL`, 2. `strlen(ph->help_summary)` is not huge 3. `strlen(ph->cmd)` is not huge and 4. `strlen(ph->cmd) is > 0` (some embedded systems may have trouble with a %-6s and length 0) 6. Does `ph->cmd, ph->help_summary` contain not control characters 7. Is `printf( "  %-6s ...` return value reasonable?

Comment: For the two lines that print, the input strings are literals i.e. they are part of the binary and statically allocated. So, I would second clux and really verify the contents of the structures that are being printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My driver had some debug code filled with printf()'s that wasn't commented out on release.... I have since removed it and the problem has gone away. Somehow that must have caused some problems in memory.

Comment: The implementation of the stdout stream support on your platform is unknown to us - it will be target/retarget/implementation and (possibly OS if you have one) specific.

Comment: Probably you where using printf from inside and outside an interrupt (the Ethernet interrupt in your case). Printf isn't reentrant. Also, be warned that printf uses heap.